# isnull function vs IS NULL

Tags: null, isnull

as part of a case statement in a wider sql script, I have the following:

WHEN KWB.ASYCONDTYPE IN ('CIVIL','CIVIL2') AND KWB.CIVCONDGRADE is null THEN 'NO CIVIL CG'

This will set the field to 'NO CIVIL CG' for 1405 records

WHEN KWB.ASYCONDTYPE IN ('CIVIL','CIVIL2') AND ISNULL(KWB.CIVCONDGRADE,'') = '' THEN 'NO CIVIL CG'

This will set the field for 1410 records, which would appear to be the right answer,
as the 5 fields not set in the first instance have ASYCONDTYPE = 'CIVIL' and CIVCONDGRADE is indeed NULL

Slightly worrying, as I'd expect them to produce the same result, and if it wasn't for excel filtering, it might have gone unnoticed.

Can anyone provide an explanation or at least somewhere I can check in the dataset or database to enable me to understand what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

That should be becouse you got 1405 records where "KWB.CIVCONDGRADE" is actually NULL and 5 records where "KWB.CIVCONDGRADE" isn't NULL but simply an empty field.

Try to check with this query if it results 5 records:

```
WHEN KWB.ASYCONDTYPE IN ('CIVIL','CIVIL2') AND KWB.CIVCONDGRADE = '' THEN 'NO CIVIL CG'
```

Comment: Thought of that, but no, they were null